# How to parse data from Ruby array?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, watir-webdriver

I'm using watir-webdriver to scrape data from a website. When I try to import the data into the DB I get the error "can't cast Array to text".

```
def get_event_details(url)
    headless = Headless.new
    headless.start
    b = Watir::Browser.start "http://example.com"
    @event = event ={}
    if event_detail = get_html_from_url(url)
      event["title"] = b.spans(:class => "classname").collect &:text
      event["source_url"] = b.split("&year")[0] if b.include?("&year") rescue b
      event["timezone"] = 'HST'
      event
    end
    puts event
    return event
    b.close
    headless.destroy
end
```

The data being imported looks something like this:

```
{"title"=>["1", "2", "3"]}
```

After I added this bit of code

```
event["title"] = b.spans(:class => "classname").collect.map { |i| "'" + i.text + "'" }.join(", ")
```

I'm no longer getting the error but every single title is being inserted to the same column in the DB. The data being imported now looks like this:

```
{"title"=>"'1', '2', '3'"}
```

I'm not sure how to go about fixing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do a separate insert for the titles, and associate them with the event via an "event.id" or similar.

If you provide the database insert code more precise help can be given!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand,
You have the hash:

```
{"title"=>["1", "2", "3"], "source_url"=>["http://ex1.com", "http://ex2.com", "http://ex3.com"], "timezone"=>"HST"}
```

You need to add to db something like:

```
+------+------+--------+
|title |source|timezone|
+------|------|--------+
|  1   | ex1  |   HST  |
+------|------|--------+
|  2   | ex2  |   HST  |
+------+------+--------+
```

etc.
If it's true, so, you just need to:

```
[a['title']].map(&:size).max.times.each { |i|
    db.query("INSERT INTO some_db(title, source_url, timezone) VALUES ('#{a['title'][i]}', '#{a['source_url'][i]}', '#{a['timezone']}') ")
}
```

P.S. I use mysql db for this example